# Runtime error in Nested Depth Question in C

Tags: c

This is the code which I submitted in the second question of the Qualification Round of Google CodeJam but the compiler showed **RunTime Error**.
But this runs on the Code Blocks just fine.
Why is that?

> **Problem**
> Given a string of digits **S**, insert a minimum number of opening and closing parentheses into it such that the resulting string is balanced and each digit **d** is inside exactly **d** pairs of matching parentheses.
>
> Let the nesting of two parentheses within a string be the substring that occurs strictly between them. An opening parenthesis and a closing parenthesis that is further to its right are said to match if their nesting is empty, or if every parenthesis in their nesting matches with another parenthesis in their nesting. The nesting depth of a position **p** is the number of pairs of matching parentheses **m** such that **p** is included in the nesting of **m**.
>
> For example, in the following strings, all digits match their nesting depth: `0((2)1)`, `(((3))1(2))`, `((((4))))`, `((2))((2))(1)`. The first three strings have minimum length among those that have the same digits in the same order, but the last one does not since `((22)1)` also has the digits `221` and is shorter.

Given a string of digits **S**, find another string **S'**, comprised of parentheses and digits, such that:
all parentheses in **S'** match some other parenthesis,
removing any and all parentheses from **S'** results in **S**,
each digit in **S'** is equal to its nesting depth, and
**S'** is of minimum length.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int t, k = 0;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        int d, first, num = 0, brackets = 0;
        char ch = '(', ch1 = ')';
        char str1[100], str2[100] = {};
        scanf("%s", &str1);

        first = str1[0] - '0';
        num = first;
        brackets = first;

        for (int i = 0; i < first; i++) {
            strncat(str2, &ch, 1);
        }
        strncat(str2, &str1[0], 1);

        for (int i = 1; i < strlen(str1); i++) {
            d = str1[i] - '0';

            if (d == num) {
                strncat(str2, &str1[i], 1);
            } else
            if (d > num) {
                int diff = d - num;
                for (int j = 0; j < diff; j++) {
                    strncat(str2, &ch, 1);
                    brackets++;
                }
                strncat(str2, &str1[i], 1);
            } else {
                int diff = num - d;
                for (int j = 0; j < diff; j++) {
                    strncat(str2, &ch1, 1);
                    brackets--;
                }
                strncat(str2, &str1[i], 1);
            }
            num = str1[i] - '0';
        }

        while (brackets > 0) {
            strncat(str2, &ch1, 1);
            brackets--;
        }

        k++;
        printf("Case #%d: %s\n", k, str2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice problem! I think you need to count (and substract)

Comment: It would be much simpler to have an index into `str2` and write `str2[index++] = ch;` instead of `strncat(str2, &ch, 1);`. The null terminator can be added at the end: `str2[index] = '\0';`. You could also just write the characters to the output incrementally.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &str1);` -> `scanf("%99s", str1);` which makes it obvious that the array `str1` is too short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the description of the problem and found this:

```
Limits
Time limit: 20 seconds per test set.
Memory limit: 1GB.
1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
1 ≤ length of S ≤ 100.
```

So the input string can be 100 characters.

Your code is

```
char str1[100],str2[100]={};
```

so you can't store more than 99 characters.

Further, the output string may be much larger than the input.

Example:

```
Input: 909
Output (((((((((9)))))))))0(((((((((9)))))))))
```

So you need to make the output string much bigger. I haven't calculated the maximum but if you make it 20 times bigger, your safe.

```
char str1[101],str2[20 * 101]= { 0 };
          ^^^       ^^^^^^^^^    ^
```

But why have an output string at all? Simply print out the characters instead of storing them in a string.

Comment: Also hint that `= {};` is not a proper initializer in C. It is a GNU extension and a C++ feature.